# TeamCity 5.1.3 and FogBugz

Tags: teamcity, fogbugz, issue-tracking

Can I connect FogBugz to the TeamCity as a IssueTracker ? Currently I can see only 3 drivers for connect : Bugzilla,Jira and YouTrack.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but adding this XML bit to your main-config.xml (c:\build.BuildServer\config\main-config.xml) will cause TeamCity to build the link from the VCS checking comment to your fogbugz case. Our setup will link anything prefixed with case, bug, story, or fb. You can see easily how do add new prefixes as well.

```
<comment-transformation>
    <transformation-pattern search="(Case|case|Bug|bug|Story|story|fb|FB|Fb)\s+(\d+)" replace="&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; title=&quot;Click to open the case a new window&quot; href=&quot;   http://fogbugz_server/fogbugz?$2&quot;&gt;Case $2&lt;/a&gt;" description="FogBugz Case" />
</comment-transformation>
```